# Does Jack remain under arrest in the movie Titanic even when Rose frees him?

Tags: titanic

I was just wondering about the situation in *Titanic* where Jack is accused of stealing the heart of the ocean, handcuffed to a pole, and ultimately saved by Rose. Does Jack remain under arrest even after Rose frees him? I mean I understand that while the ship is thinking the crew members aren't going to worry about Jack's "theft", however, I was just wondering whether or not Jack would still technically be under arrest even after being freed. I just wanted to know whether or not officials would be after Jack if he managed to survive the sinking.

Comment: In international waters, the law of the ship is the law of the country who's flag its flying.  RMS Titanic was registered in Liverpool, so would have fallen under English law - so theoretically he could be prosecuted in the English courts for the "theft".  I'm not familiar with the law in 1912, or whether it was modified by the fact they were not on English soil - but presumably he could be held pending charges being laid against him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  As the charges were not dropped by a court or an officer he would still be under arrest.  Though I don't have the rules for the early 20th Century, the rules for arrest at the moment are as follows:

> The police can hold you for up to 24 hours before they have to charge you with a crime or release you.
>
> They can apply to hold you for up to 36 or 96 hours if you’re suspected of a serious crime, eg murder.
>
> You can be held without charge for up to 14 days If you’re arrested under the Terrorism Act.

Source: https://www.gov.uk/arrested-your-rights/how-long-you-can-be-held-in-custody

Further to that, Rose could potentially face charges for aiding the escape of a prisoner.  Again, no early 20th Century law from this one, but in March 2017 there was an [arrest in the UK](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-england-london-39297010) for "assisting an offender", which related to someone helping a prisoner escape prison

Answer (score 1):

No. The crime was never communicated to the authorities. The master of arms on the ship, and the antagonist of the movie, Rose's fiance, are both killed in the events of the sinking. The villain only tells the master of arms about the "theft" after the boat hits the ice berg, and the master of arms only detains Jack after that. No where in the "present" of the film does anyone suggest the Heart was stolen or even know about Jack. Only Rose does and she never tells a soul.

Since everyone that knew about the Heart was either killed or stayed quiet about it, no, Jack would not be a suspect in a crime no one knows about. As far as anyone else is concerned, the Heart sunk into the Ocean the night of the Titanic.

Comment: Cal did not die on the night of sinking. Rose tells about how he killed himself during the great depression when on the research ship.
See also https://jamescameronstitanic.fandom.com/wiki/Caledon_Hockley#Later_life_and_death